# How to solve TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined?

Tags: angular

I am not sure why I am getting this error message.

I've checked the SO threads on this issue but most seem to be trying to access a property on an undefined array.

I don't believe that is my issue.

This is my code where I am getting this error.

```
addGizmo() {
    let gizmo = new gizmo();
    this.gizmoSubject.next(gizmo);    
    let dialogEdit = this.dialog.open(DialogGizmoAddEdit,
      {
        width: "300px",
        data: { gizmo: this.gizmoSubject.getValue(), inEditMode: false },
      });

    dialogEdit.afterClosed().subscribe(x => {
      if (x !== false) {
        this.loadGizmos();
        this.dataCatalogService.addGizmo(x)
        .subscribe(
          () => this.loadGizmos(),
          error => this.handleError(error)
        );
      }
    });
  };
```

I can post more code if needed but the the "addGizmo" method calls my API adds the gizmo to the DB and returns a string back.  I've tested the API inside as well as outside of Angular and I don't see an issue there.

The error appears to be occurring in the subscribe method.  At that point it has already added the gizmo to the DB.

Stepping through the code I never see loadGizmo's get called.

```
Angular Setup:
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 10.5.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.6
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cdk                      6.3.1
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@angular/material                 6.3.1
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.2.1
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.12.1
```

Comment: can you try an alert in if condition to check if the condition is satisfying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the API.  Even though it returned a status code of 200 with it's value, my interceptor was catching the following error in it's response.

```
Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0
```

This has to do with the fact that I am sending json in the body to the API and it appears it is assuming that the response should be json as well, when in this case it is returning a string.

I'm not sure how to handle this but I can open up another question if I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

`x` could be undefined.

```
console.log(undefined !== false);
// prints true
```

Since there is no where in your coding example where property `0` is read or an array accessor is used. The error is happening elsewhere.

When you write `if(x !== false)` it's not the same logic as `if(x)`.